# QSerialPort - Convert char to Hex

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing an app with Qt and I have to read frames and check each byte to see if its values are correct.

```
QSerialPort serial;
QByteArray data = serial.readAll();
```

I well receive bytes but I don't know how to check if they are well equal to my hex values. I'd like to do something like this:

```
if (data[0] == 0x02) {
    // my code
}
```

My question will probably be stupid for most of you but I don't find any answer :(

Comment: `if (data[0] == 0x02) { /* my code*/ }` This looks good, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: For read only access usage of data.at(0) might be more efficient than data[0] but both should work. So you forgot to describe your issue.

Comment: Ah yes you're right it works but I get an error message: Semantic error, use of overloaded '==' is ambiguous (with operand types QByteRef and int). I had to add data[0].operator char  == 0x02 to fix it. Is it the right way?

Comment: if you need char then use '\x02' not 0x02.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your replies, they all work fine